# Scala Generic type from string

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I am new to scala. I have googled with not much success on how to acquire generic type from a string. My need is - I will pass a string 'className' to a function, that should convert to a type and substitute to a Generic type parameter as following.

```
import org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

case class TestClassA(i: Int, s: String)
case class TestClassB(f: Double, s: String)

val className: String = "TestClassA"

def TestFunction(className: String, jsonStr: String): Unit = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    var json = parse(jsonStr)
    // Do something with className to extract type
    val testClassAObj = json.extract["etracted TestClassA"]

    println(testClassAObj.i)


    ...
}

TestFunction(className)
```

I expect testClassAObj to be of instance of TestClassA.

I am confused on how to do this. Any help here is appreciated

Comment: This seems like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you provide reasons you want to do this?

Comment: Edited the question. Hope that helps

Comment: Perhaps this question (and the solution) might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400209/reflect-type-name-in-string-to-actual-type-in-scala

Comment: Thanks @Eric. This link helps me create an instance with a default value. But i am looking to  extract the type and create a instance by some other generic function which decides its value.